# Access virtuemart cart and shop for registered user only

Tags: joomla, shopping-cart, virtuemart, cart

Can i restrict the access permission for virtuemart cart and shop. It is my client requirement to show add to cart and user cart only for registered user and whenever any visitor try to get cart it will be redirected on login page.
have any possibility in virtuemart to fix access permission for non register user OR I should to change shop module code to restrict the access.
Need your suggestion very fast...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as the cart is concerned, if you have it in a module then you simply need to set the access level to registered. For the cart flypage, you will need to set up a menu item for that page and set the access level to registered. The menu item can be in a hidden menu, it does not have to be displayed anywhere for this to work. As far as the add to cart button, You just need to make a modification to the theme, look for addtocart_form.tpl.php. You can put a simple conditional statement that displays a message if the user is not logged in. Here is a good example of using the user object in Joomla -

http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object

You could easily copy the example on this page for the add to cart form.